# Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Show that the map $\varphi: G\to G/H$ sending $\varphi(g)=g+H$ is well defined.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Show that the map $\varphi: G\to G/H$ sending $\varphi(g)=g+H$ is well defined.

I think this should be very simple, but I am not sure where to start with this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does $H/G$ mean?

Comment: H is a normal subgroup of G. I will edit the question, thank you.

Comment: "addition" and "multiplication" are just two different notations for operations, so there is nothing to be thrown-off by.

Comment: Addition and multiplication are just binary operations. Typically the $+$ is reserved for abelian groups but there is no reason to prefer $gH$ to $g+H$ other than convention.

Comment: Do you know what "well-defined" means?

Answer (score 1):

If $g=g'$, then $g-g'=0\in H$.

By the definition of cosets of $H$, $g+H=g'+H$.

Answer (score 0):

If $g=g'$ then by algebraic substitution $\varphi(g)=g+H=g'+H=\varphi(g')$.

Comment: I have a feeling that a lot of folks are going to look at this and feel like you just used the word "algebraic substitution" for the conclusion, and then assumed the conclusion...  I'm not saying for sure it is circular, because I have been told before there is some sort of rigorous notion of substitution that makes this explanation true. It's just that I never understood why we wouldn't just use regular definitions in a case like this.

Comment: For a map to be well defined then equal input values, no matter how they are represented or described or formulated, must yield equal output values. Throughout mathematics and symbolic logic, especially algebra, when $x=y$ when can interchange $x,y$ in equations. This is a very plain tautology.

Comment: @rschwieb. Perhaps, you should also ask whether the map $g+H\mapsto g^2+H$ is well defined or whether the canonical group operation on the quotient $\frac{G}{H}$ is well defined.

Comment: I'm well aware that it's correct, but my point is that it looks like the entire explanation was swept under a rug in the form of a vocabulary word.  I imagine it would benefit from a careful sentence or two explaining  when one may apply the reasoning.

Comment: I thought algebraic substitution meant this: given a set with operations, write a formula with finitely many symbols connected by the operations.  Then if $g=h$ in the set, you the formulas you get when you substitute $g$ for one of the symbols is equal to the expression with $h$ substituted for the same symbol.  That makes complete sense and matches what I think most people think of as substitution.   But you see there's a curveball above: $x+H$ is not written in terms of the operation of $g$. So I guess my definition with operations is too restrictive.

Comment: @rschwieb. I definitely like the idea of good illustrative explanation as well but sometimes, like here I believe, it may appear there is more being asked when in fact there really isn't. The issues with well defined maps on cosets usually concern coset representation but here the operation is defined on the group itself and is well defined for the simple reason given above. More explanation would be necessary to explain why the map $g+H\mapsto g^2+H$ is well defined. Do you notice the difference in this last example ? $(g^2:=g+g)$